# Combobox returns System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.x

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding

Trying to get selected value from combobox but it returns System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.x

```
private void mycmb_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
        mycmb.ItemsSource = RE.Scanner.ToList();
        mycmb.DisplayMemberPath = "Descr";
    }
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
        string _scanner0 = int.Parse(mycmb.SelectedValue.ToString());
        string _scanner1 = mycbr.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string _scanner2 = mycbr.SelectedValuePath.ToString();
        string _scanner3 = mycbr.text.ToString();
    }

WHY?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast your `ComboBox.SelectedItem` to a `Scanner` object and grab the info from there.

```
Scanner scanner = (Scanner)mycbr.SelectedItem;
string desc=scanner.Descr;
```